# Imcompatible types: byte cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java, android, byte

I have a class with values which I construct as object and send message to main handler. I can work with `int` without any trouble but some of the values are boolean. This is where I run into the following error in bytes[5] and bytes[6]

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[259];

message_to_device = new MyDevice(bytes[3], //int
                                 bytes[4], //int
                                 bytes[5], // boolean
                                 bytes[6]  // boolean);
                                        
Message message = Message.obtain();
message.obj = message_to_device;
message.what = MESSAGE;
mhandler.sendMessage(message);
```

I have come across `BitSet`, will that be any of use? I am not so familiar with bits and byes in Android yet. How can I proceed?

Comment: Maybe you could pass as a parameter, the boolean result of the comparison, e.g `bytes[5] == 1` .

Comment: `bytes[5] != 0, bytes[6] != 0);`

Comment: or `bytes[5] != (byte) 0, bytes[6] != (byte) 0`.

Comment: The question to answer is, what are the 3rd and 4th arguments to the MyDevice constructor supposed to *mean*, and what is their relationship to the numbers stored in bytes[5] and bytes[6]?  It may be true that you're only interested in whether the byte value is zero or not zero, as per previous comments, but that is not necessarily so. You have to know what the meaning is and code accordingly.

Comment: thank you guys. seems to be working. seems more simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be explicitly casted:

```
new MyDevice(
    (int)       bytes[3], // integer value
    (int)       bytes[4], // integer value
    bytes[5] != (byte) 0, // boolean result
    bytes[6] != (byte) 0  // boolean result
);
```

But it also works without casting, since in Java one can use `byte` instead of `int`:

```
new MyDevice(bytes[3], bytes[4], bytes[5] != 0, bytes[6] != 0);
```

As the [definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for `byte` reads:

> They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code;
>
> the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

Or add a constructor alike: `public MyDevice(byte, byte, byte, byte)` or even `public MyDevice(byte[])`. `MyDevice` could even have setters, accepting `byte` values, which set `boolean` fields. For example:

```
class MyDevice {
    // public MyDevice(int arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3) {}
    public MyDevice(byte arg0, byte arg1, byte arg2, byte arg3) {}
    public MyDevice(byte[] arg0) {}
}
```

Comment: do we need casting at all? and why that strange order , `byte[5] != 0` *looks more natural* IMO

Comment: actually operands will be converted to `int`: see [15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) "If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, ..., binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger `byte` & `int` are a special case; unlike other data-types. In the IDE, it does at least not gray out the casts - and so I left both versions.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your comment, how is `int` a special case? it is kind of the default for integral types that are not `long`.... 1) no need to cast `byte` to `int` (first 2 arguments) - eventually needs masking wiht `& 0xFF`; 2) no need to cast `0` to`byte`, it will be cast back to `int` anyways for equality operation (last 2 arguments)

Comment: I downvoted based on the unnecessary casting, and the inverted comparison order. These are both coding tics that I would prefer not to see replicated.

Comment: @another-dave reverted the order of comparison, but left the explicit casting - this only works without casting, because `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` are integer data-types.